# En un temps vs dans un temps : ont-ils le même sens ?

Tags: sens, prépositions

De *l’Express*:

> Est-ce important, pour un journal ... de rappeler qu’il est né dans les années 1950, **en** un temps où Vincent Auriol était président de la République ...

Pourrait-on utiliser aussi bien "**dans** un temps" ici ? Si oui, y a-t-il une différence du sens ?

Comment: I normally associate "dans" + an amount of time as that amount of time later (dans une heure = an hour from now).

Comment: @LukeSawczak I understand that, but I think "un temps où Vincent Auriol était président de la République" is different. This is clearly not an amount of time.

Comment: Agreed — I just don't know if *dans* can express that relationship to time too. I guess we'll wait to see it confirmed by someone more knowledgeable :)

Comment: Their sentence is quite odd. The most common way to express what they wanted to say is "à une époque où Vincent Auriol était[...]".

Comment: I am a French native speaker and I agree with [that](https://www.thoughtco.com/learn-essential-french-prepositions-4078684). Now I can't tell you much execpt for me, in this particular case, "dans" sounds really really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dit "en un temps où.." pour rappeler le temps de l'action, son contexte. On aurait pu dire "au temps de.." mais alors c'est beaucoup plus ancien et plus flou : comme " au temps des calèches..." . Par contre "dans un même temps..." veut dire simultanément.